# Paragraph filling for org-mode inside latex environment

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, org-mode

I started using org-mode to write mathematical papers so I make a heavy use of latex environments such as `proof`, `theorem`, `lemma`, etc. For example I often write

```
\begin{proof}

a very long proof follows

\end{proof}
```

The problem is that in org-mode the `fill-paragraph` (or `M-q`) doesn't work inside latex environments.  This complicates my life because some proofs can be very long, reaching several pages when compiled to pdf, and I am unable to efficiently format them in org-mode.  I couldn't find any information in the manual on options controlling paragraph filling.  Is it possible to enable `fill-paragraph` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappears if you use an org block instead of a latex environment:

```
#+BEGIN_proof 
...
#+END_proof
```

This gets exported as `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}`. It also lets you use org syntax inside the block, and fill paragraph works.

if you don't want to do that, maybe try `visual-line-mode` as a workaround.

**Edit: change fill-paragraph behaviour**

If you want fill paragraph to work in latex environments, you have to dig a little deeper. Filling is done by `org-fill-paragraph` in `org.el` and this function ignores latex environments by default. To change this, go to the end of the function and replace

```
  ;; Ignore every other element.
  (otherwise t)
```

with

```
  (latex-environment nil) ;; use default fill-paragraph
  ;; Ignore every other element.
  (otherwise t)
```

If you'd rather not change the org sources, you could use advice instead, e.g.

```
(defun org-fill-paragraph--latex-environment (&rest args)
  "Use default fill-paragraph in latex environments."
  (not (eql (org-element-type (org-element-context)) 'latex-environment)))

(advice-add 'org-fill-paragraph :before-while #'org-fill-paragraph--latex-environment)
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, and it works quite well (you can even nest environments).  The downside is I loose some of the reftex functionality (reftex can no longer classify labels correctly) and I cannot use yasnippet for latex without rewriting them, so a total conversion to `#+begin_...` and `#+end_...` is not the best option.  I experimented for a while and it turns out I can get the advantages of both approaches by using #+begin_proof for proofs and other long environments and by using \begin{equation} inside the #+begin_proof.  So in the end your answer solves the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: added another solution

Comment: The updated answer is more to the point and works perfectly for me!  Is there any motivation behind disabling the `fill-paragraph` when inside latex environment?

Answer (score 1):

I have a command that you could bind to M-q in Org:

```
(defun leuven-good-old-fill-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-paragraph-function nil)
        (adaptive-fill-function nil))
    (fill-paragraph)))
```

Though, I don't understand either why it's not enabled by default. Maybe a question for the Org ML?