# Unwrap org-mode code blocks

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Is there a way to wrap text in org-mode without wrapping babel code blocks? Often times I run into a situation where a line of code is wider than my page and (ideally) should keep going. But because I have line wrapping enabled for the rest of the buffer, it gets wrapped as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using @fniessen code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26912281/8544157):

```
(defun leuven-good-old-fill-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fill-paragraph-function nil)
        (adaptive-fill-function nil))
    (fill-paragraph)))
(define-key org-mode-map "\M-q" 'leuven-good-old-fill-paragraph)
```

In this example `M-q` is bound to `fill-paragraph`, you keep the buffer unwrapped and use `M-q` on selected paragraphs to wrap.

Comment: Thanks @manandearth! I'm actually looking to do the exact inverse of this. I keep org-mode wrapped but want to leave all code blocks un-wrapped...

Comment: It is also annoying to have to keep using `M-q` all the time. I think that there should be a way for org-mode to automatically wrap/unwrap descriptive text from programming code. Big +1 on this.